# Pushforward of a log canonical pair

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

This question comes from learning the paper "Existence of minimal models for varieties of log general type", where they define the log terminal model (See Definition 3.6.7). However, the question itself does not need that definition.

Let $\pi: X \to U$ be a projective morphism of normal quasi-projective varieties. Suppose that $K_X + \Delta$ is log canonical and let $\phi: X -\to Y$ be a birational contraction of normal quasi-projective varieties over $U$, where $Y$ is projective over $U$ (here, $\phi$ is a "birational contraction" means $\phi^{-1}$ does not contract any divisor, for example, when $\phi$ is a morphism). Set $\Gamma=\phi_* \Delta$. Then is it true $$\phi_*(K_X + \Delta)=K_Y +\Gamma\quad?$$

I am equally satisfied with an answer in the simplified case as $U$ is a point, or $\phi$ is a morphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since 
$$\phi_*K_X=K_Y.$$
Here is the reason. We take a common resolution of $X$ and $Y$, say
$$
p:W\rightarrow X,  \\q: W \rightarrow Y.
$$
Then we can right 
$$
K_W-p^*K_X=E,\\
K_W-q^*K_Y=F,
$$
where $E$ is exceptional over $X$ (and over $Y$ because "contraction") and $F$ is exceptional over $Y$. If apply $q_*$ to 
$$
p^*K_X+E=q^*K_Y=F,
$$ 
we get the equality.

Comment: Why $\phi_*(K_X)=K_Y$? Could you point out some reference?

Comment: I think the key words here are "Grauert-Reimenschneider vanishing theorem."

Comment: @dhy Which form of the theorem do you mean, for the G-R vanishing theorem I check in "Positivity of algebraic geometry" (THM 4.3.9), it only states that $R^i\phi_*(K_X)=0$ for $i>0$.

Comment: I usually take $\phi_*(K_X)=(K_Y)$ as part of the G-R vanishing theorem statement. Actually though, I think G-R usually has stronger conditions than the ones you assume...

Comment: $\phi_* K_X = K_Y$ has nothing to do with Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing I think. The edit to the question gives one way to see it.  Here is another.  Both $X$ and $Y$ are normal and they coincide on an open set $U$ whose complement has codimension 2 on $Y$.  $K_X$ is any divisor such that $O_X(K_X) \cong \omega_X$ and $K_Y$ is any divisor such that $O_Y(K_Y) \cong \omega_Y$.  If I have a divisor $K_X$, this gives me a divisor $K_U = K_X|_U$.  But since the complement of $U$ has codimension 2 on $Y$, $K_U$ uniquely determines a choice of $K_Y$ such that $\phi_* K_X = K_Y$.

Comment: Of course, there are other choice of $K_Y$ too (although each one comes from a choice of some $K_X$). 
  
   It is worth emphasizing that just because $\phi_* K_X = K_Y$ does not mean that $\phi_* \omega_X = \omega_Y$ (this latter condition is basically rational singularities).

Comment: @KarlSchwede Thank you so much!! However, I am a little worry about the consistency on the definition of $\omega_X$. One the one hand, it is defined using $Ext$; on the other, as in the Example 4.3.12 in "Positivity of algebraic geometry", they define ""Grauert-Reimenschneider canonical sheaf" of $X$, by choosing any resolution $\mu: X' \to X$, and define $\omega_X = \mu_* \mathcal{O}_{X'}(K_{X'})$. If one use this definition, then it certainly satisfies $\phi_*(\omega_X) = \omega_Y$. This means the two definitions are not the same?

Comment: Moreover, I had a stupid question: if $D$ is a Weil divisor on $X$, then $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is defined to be the subsheaf of $K(X)$ by $\mathcal{O}(D)(U)= \{f \mid (f)|_U+D|_U \geq 0, f\in K(X)\}$ (where $(f)$ evaluated with respect to the structure sheaf of $X$). Is that correct?

Comment: @KarlSchwede Sorry, I realized that in the definition of $\omega_X$, it is written to be $\omega_X: = \mu_* \mathcal{O}_{X'}(K_X)$ for a resolution $\mu: X' \to X$, then does this consistent with the usual definition using $Ext$? (Because my version of the book "Positivity of algebraic geometry" is a draft version, I am not sure if this is the correct definition... )

Comment: I don't think people typically define $\omega_X = \mu_* \O_{X'}(K_{X'})$.  That is *not* a sheaf which corresponds to a divisor, it does *not* coincide with the $\text{Ext}$ definition.  It does satisfy various Kodaira-type vanishing theorems though.  I would *NOT* use that definition as that of the canonical sheaf (it is really a early version of the multiplier ideal).  Hopefully this helps.